# Issue with data sources that are created through the Pentaho Admin Console

Tags: pentaho

Issue with data sources that are created through the Pentaho Admin Console ,Now my MySQL IP has been changes, i did modification in my BI server .
But Pentaho Admin console in not up .!
From logs i found this is having

```
01:24:40,370 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceSystemListener: PooledDatasourceSystemListener.ERROR_0003 - Unable to pool datasource object: MyLocalDatabase caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
01:24:40,857 WARN  [PersistenceEngine] Falling back to built-in config
```

This MyLocalDatabase  database Created at Pentaho Admin Console has to be changed with new IP . Do any one help me to know , which file consists of datasources that are  created through the Pentaho Admin Console

My PAC is down, no error in server.log file

Comment: My PAC is up , but it is showing Loading... dialog box form long time .

Comment: Got connection time out error

Comment: Errors from server.log file:-

2013-07-16 02:02:58,628 INFO [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 02:02:58,628 INFO [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
2013-07-16 02:02:58,920 INFO [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 02:02:58,920 INFO [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasource information is kept in the hibernate database. 
By default, this is kept in an hypersonic database that is launched when you start the BI server. Check context.xml in webapps/pentaho/META-INF to make sure.

There's a DATASOURCE table in there that stores the data source definitions.