# Pentaho admin console is up with errors

Tags: pentaho

After restarting my pentaho server , admin console is not up, this throw-ed me following errors ,

This would be the extension of [Issue with data sources that are created through the Pentaho Admin Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669760/issue-with-data-sources-that-are-created-through-the-pentaho-admin-console) post .

Do any 1 faced this, do any one have an idea about this

```
2013-07-16 03:24:52,965 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
2013-07-16 03:28:01,778 ERROR [com.pentaho.pac.server.PacProServiceImpl]
org.pentaho.pac.server.common.ProxyException: Connection timed out
        at org.pentaho.pac.server.common.ThreadSafeHttpClient.executeMethod(ThreadSafeHttpClient.java:183)
        at org.pentaho.pac.server.common.ThreadSafeHttpClient.execRemoteMethod(ThreadSafeHttpClient.java:147)
        at org.pentaho.pac.server.common.ThreadSafeHttpClient.execRemoteMethod(ThreadSafeHttpClient.java:100)
        at org.pentaho.pac.server.common.BiServerTrustedProxy.execRemoteMethod(BiServerTrustedProxy.java:93)
        at com.pentaho.pac.server.PacProServiceImpl.k(SourceFile:1175)
        at com.pentaho.pac.server.PacProServiceImpl.q(SourceFile:1193)
        at com.pentaho.pac.server.PacProServiceImpl.getTestResult(SourceFile:750)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:285)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:835)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:638)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:208)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:378)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:226)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.pentaho.pac.server.common.ThreadSafeHttpClient.executeMethod(ThreadSafeHttpClient.java:163)
        ... 30 more
2013-07-16 03:31:10,786 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 03:31:10,786 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
2013-07-16 03:31:10,970 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 03:31:10,970 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
2013-07-16 03:34:19,784 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 03:34:19,785 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
2013-07-16 03:34:19,960 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
2013-07-16 03:34:19,960 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
```

Comment: do anyone there with a solution or advise

Answer (score 0):

Your BI server is not starting up, probably. Can you access the BI server homepage?

Comment: Are you able to get from the log the url that's being called by PAC? Which is it? What happens when you run it in a browser?